# Doctrine cascade on OneToMany does not set the parent object?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many

I have a User objects which has many Journal entries.

The user class contains a $userJournals property and the required add/remove functions, as below:

```
class User{
   ....
   /**
   * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
   *
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="models\UserJournal", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
   */
   protected $userJournals;
   ....

   public function addUserJournal(\models\UserJournal $userJournal)
   {
          $this->userJournals->add($userJournal);
          return $this;
   }
 }
```

The UserJournal class contains the User object, and a getter/setter for it. The annotation for the $user is here:

```
   class UserJournal
   {
   /**
   * @var models\User
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="models\User", inversedBy="userJournals", cascade={"persist"})
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
   * })
   */
   protected $user;
}
```

My understanding is that cascade persist makes it so I do not have to set the User on the UserJournal, I can just add the UserJournal to the User, save the User, and it will work.

```
    $user = $this->getRepository('User')->find(1);

    $userJournal = new models\UserJournal();
    $userJournal->setText('testCode');
    $user->addUserJournal($userJournal);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

However, this code produces a SQL error that user_id cannot be null on the UserJournal.

Isn't there a way to do this without having to do `$userJournal->setUser($user);` in this code or in the addUserJournal() function?

Comment: "Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes." (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html). In your case this is UserJournal.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't explain anything to me. The UserJournal is attempting to save but has no $user set. How do I get it to set the $user? If you're saying make User the owner, the documentation doesn't show any examples of how to do that

Comment: Why not simply do the following: $userJournal->addUser($user);
    $em->persist($userJournal); ?  (and remove  $user->addUserJournal($userJournal);
    $em->persist($user);) Or clarify why you explicitly want to persist the user?

Comment: Because we will be making many other changes to the user, and the user needs to be persisted.

Comment: You're right. I just ran a test, it worked in my case.

Comment: You can make changes to User they will be persisted when calling $em->persist($userJournal);

Comment: That just seems backwards. What if I want to add another entity to a child of User, and save both that and the journals, and change their username.. and so to do all that I persist userJournal? What if I added 3 journals?

Comment: You say it works when you do it the way I have my sample code?

Comment: to achieve all this i would simply set the User to UserJournal when inside your addUserJournal method. If you need to add a couple of journals, this will do the job, as you can chain the method calls.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing - I just thought Doctrine was supposed to handle that. I'll have to add that logic in every add* method but oh well. Better to find out now. :)

Comment: Definitely, simply use the add. It's only one line of code.

Comment: One line of code in EVERY add* function we have.