# Symfony2 - How update an entity when anyone of its children is updated

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have three entities in my project: Exam, Exercise and Question.

I would like that when I update a Question object, which is child of an Exercise object, this is updated too, and then, the Exam object which is parent of Exercise is updated too.

I need to save the datetime when they were updated, so in this way, I have a "modified" field in each class.

Here is my code:

```
class Exam
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="mark", type="float")
 */
private $mark;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $modified;
}



class Exercise
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="points", type="float")
 */
private $points;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $modified;
}



class Question
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="questionText", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $questionText;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $modified;
}
```

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865955/doctrine-cascade-on-onetomany-does-not-set-the-parent-object ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the child of the object you need to add cascade={"persist"} to the relationship, have a look at:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

To set the modified value, you can use in your entity a lifecycle events, it would be something like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function setModifiedValue()
{
    $this->modified= new \DateTime();
}
```

You might also want to use PrePersist to set the timedate when the object was created. More info at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Sorry if the syntax is wrong, I normally use YAML but it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I needed to add the cascade={"persist"} and all were perfect. For your suggestion about the prePersist, I don't need this function because I set the modified field in the constructor of the class. Thank you!!